# PHP post two values in one field, one of which is hidden

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way that I can post two values at the same time from a single field in a table but hide one from the user?

I would like the following form to post the values `ID` and `reason_name` when it is submitted but have the user only be able to see (and edit in the text box) the `reason_name`.

```
<form name="add_positioning" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <table border="1" class="autoTable_pos">
        <tr>
            <td>Positioning</td><td> </td></tr>
        <?
        $sql= "SELECT * FROM gradeReason WHERE reason_userID = $user_id AND category = 'positioning' AND current = 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="reason[]" size="25" value="<? echo $row['reason_name']; ?>"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delRow_pos"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <?
        }
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="reason[]" size="25"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delRow_pos"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" name="save_reasons"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

The form POST action so far (basic echo at the moment for my own sanity to check that it posts the values correctly, which it does...)

```
if(isset($_POST['save_reasons'])) {   
    foreach($_POST['reason'] as $item) {
        echo $item.'<br/>';
    }
}
```

This table displays the values that are held in a database but enables the user to add more values by dynamically adding a new row (using `JQUERY` I haven't included) to the table when they type in an empty one at the bottom and also allows them to edit or delete existing values.

For each value posted I intend to check if the `ID` value is empty, if it is it means that it is a new value and enter a new record into the database, if it isn't update the existing record in the database with the corresponding `ID`.  I don't have a problem writing that bit, I just can't think how to get the `ID` value posted as well as the `reason_name` while keeping `ID` hidden from the user.

Comment: `SESSION` is here for you :)

Comment: each record has it's own ID, how would SESSION help?

Comment: store them in session if you don't want to show them to user. Otherwise anything in html can be viewed by user

Comment: I get that but I'm not sure how I would do that using form created with a while loop?

Comment: You could use a hidden field but the user can still 'see' that.

Comment: I thought of the hidden field but I couldn't think how to make that work with the array method I used, thats where I'm stuck

Comment: @tatty27: simply store those data fetched by the while loop in an array stored as `SESSION` data. for an example, `$_SESSION['data'][$i]=$var`

Comment: anyone know why this was downvoted?  Just like to know so whatever it was that I did wrong I don't do again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the ID to the name attribute of the Text boxes of the reasons loaded from the DB. Leave the other Text boxes added using JQ without the ID. 
E.g.
Text box which shows the existing reason loaded from the DB

```
 <input type="text" name="reason[][ID]" size="25"/>
```

Text box added with JQ

```
<input type="text" name="reason[]" size="25"/>
```

Then once you submit the form you get you will get the following array.

```
array
```

'reason' => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          14 => string 'VAL1' (length=4)
      1 => string 'VAL2' (length=5)

By checking for an array in the each element in the "reason" array, you can differentiate two type of Text Boxes.

Here is the complete code I have tested.

```
<?PHP
//var_dump($_POST);
foreach($_POST['reason'] as $item=>$value)
{
    if(is_array($value)){
        foreach($value as $ID=>$reason)
        {
            echo "Existing Reason : ".$ID." - ".$reason."<br>";
        }   
    }
    else{
        echo "New Reason : ".$item." - ".$value.'<br/>';
    }


}     
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="reason[][14]" size="25" value="aaaa"/>
  <input type="text" name="reason[]" size="25" value="bbbbb"/>
  <input name="" type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the id is at $row['reason_id'] I think you want:

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="reason_id[<? echo $i; ?>]" size="25" value="<? echo $row['reason_id']; ?>"/>
            <input type="text" name="reason[<? echo $i; ?>]" size="25" value="<? echo $row['reason_name']; ?>"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delRow_pos"/></td></tr>
<? $i++ } ?>
```

This way you can later

```
if(isset($_POST['save_reasons'])) {   
    foreach($_POST['reason'] as $key => $item) {
        $id = $_POST['reason_id'][$key];
        echo $id . " " . $item.'<br/>';
    }
}
```